# /angularfire2/index has no exported member 'AngularFire'

Tags: angular, firebase, import, angular-cli, angularfire2

Can't fix this problem:

app.component.ts

```
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

/angularfire2/index has no exported member 'AngularFire',
/angularfire2/index has no exported member 'AuthProviders',
/angularfire2/index has no exported member 'AuthMethods '
```

but in app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
```

works fine and I can initialize the app

package.json

```
"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"firebase": "^3.9.0",
...
"devDependencies": {...
"ts-node": "~2.0.0",
"tslint": "~4.5.0",
"typescript": "~2.2.0"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are using angularfire2@4.0.0+, there is no `AngularFire` exported any more. Instead, you shall use it as below:

```
// import AngularFireAuthModule at NgModule
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';


import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
// inject 
construstor(afa: AngularFireAuth) {
  afa.auth.signInWithPopup()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just reinstalled angularfire2 to version 2.0.0-beta.7 and everything worked!  What a fragile thing this angular2 is :)

Comment: @KatyaKaterinaa ok, glad to hear you have come through it.

Comment: See our AngularFire2 2.0 => 4.0 transition guide here https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md, there are benefits to the changes

Comment: `import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2/auth';` but getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to AngularFire2 4.0 solve my issue

Migration Guide:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md

Comment: Are you sure this answers the question above? OP apparently already has af 4.

Comment: I was using AngularFire2 2.0 and upgraded to above solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is :**

With the `"angularfire2": "^5.1.1",`

you need this libraries too:

```
"rxfire": "^3.3.5",
"rxjs": "6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
```