# Add AngularFire to constructor

Tags: angular, angularfire2

Hej I have problem with adding AngularFire to constructor at app.component.ts.

I have watching 4 courses realted with AngularFire and everybody add AngularFire to constructor at app.component.ts.

My code look like that:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Test App';


  constructor(private af: AngularFire){

  }
}
```

VisualCode is telling me that he don't know what is AngularFire. 
But even if I try add import from angularfire2 I have access only to  AngularFireModule

I forget install something or what can be an issue?
Yes, I used npm install angularfire --save

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777706/angularfire2-index-has-no-exported-member-angularfire

Comment: You can try and follow this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/build-real-time-chat-angular-4-firebase-eliran-elnasi/ to use firebase with Angular. (Disclaimer: I wrote this)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/angularfire2/index has no exported member 'AngularFire'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777706/angularfire2-index-has-no-exported-member-angularfire)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong. You are installing angularjs version I think. Use this

```
npm install firebase angularfire2 --save
```

Then import it doing this inside your component

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
```

Your constructor should look like this

```
constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {

}
```

Here https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Angularfire, there is no exported member  AngularFire on AngularFire 5.0.

```
 constructor(afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {
  afDb.list<Item>('items').valueChanges().subscribe(console.log);
}
The same concepts apply to FirebaseObjectObservable to AngularFireObject
```

See [5.0 migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md)