# Angular Firebase: issue with imports

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I created a service file to manage my firebase user authentication. But, I am getting errors for the imports that are found in the auth.service.ts file. Below is the error followed by the imports and the code from the ts file.

ERRORS:

ERROR in src/app/core/auth.service.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Zakariah Siyaji/Desktop/or-api/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AngularFireAuth'.
src/app/core/auth.service.ts(2,27): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Zakariah Siyaji/Desktop/or-api/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AngularFireDatabase'.
src/app/core/auth.service.ts(2,48): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Zakariah Siyaji/Desktop/or-api/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'FirebaseAuthState'.
src/app/core/auth.service.ts(2,67): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Zakariah Siyaji/Desktop/or-api/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AuthProviders'.
src/app/core/auth.service.ts(2,82): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Zakariah Siyaji/Desktop/or-api/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AuthMethods'.
src/app/core/auth.service.ts(2,95): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Zakariah Siyaji/Desktop/or-api/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AngularFire'.

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Imports:

import { AngularFireAuth, AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseAuthState, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, AngularFire } from "angularfire2";

angularfire2 is also found in the package.json folder with version number: "^5.0.0-rc.11"

code:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth, AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseAuthState, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, AngularFire } from "angularfire2";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class AuthService {
  authState: FirebaseAuthState = null;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private router: Router) {
    af.auth.subscribe((auth) => {
      this.authState = auth;
    });
  }


  //Return true if user is logged in
  get authenticated(): boolean {
  return this.authState !== null;
}
  //Returns current user
  get currentUser(): any {
  return this.authenticated ? this.authState.auth : null;
}

 //Returns current user UID
 get currentUserId(): string {
 return this.authenticated ? this.authState.uid : '';
}

// Anonymous User
get currentUserAnonymous(): boolean {
return this.authenticated ? this.authState.Anonymous : false
}

//Returns current user display name or guest
get currentUserDisplayName(): string {

if (!this.authenticated) { return 'GUEST' }
else if (this.currentUserAnonymous) { return 'ANONYMOUS'}
else { return this.authState.auth.displayName || 'OAUTH USER'}

}

//login through a Gmail account
googleLogin(): Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
return this.socialSignIn(AuthProviders.Google);
}

private socialSignIn(provider: number): Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
  return this.af.auth.login({provider, method: AuthMethods.popup})
  .then(() => this.updateUserData() )
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

private updateUserData(): void {
  //Writes user name and email to realtime db
  //useful if your app displays information about users or for admin features

  let path = `users/${this.currentUserId}`; //Endpoint on Firebase
  let data = { name: this.currentUser.displayName, email: this.currentUser.email, }

  this.db.object(path).update(data)
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
}


}
```

Comment: I'll try to find out. But it is something related to ES5 configuration and node. Try to add node to your tsconfig.spec.json types array.

Comment: try to do this. `npm install firebase angularfire2@next --save`

Comment: The following is my tsconfig.spec.json code: {
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777706/angularfire2-index-has-no-exported-member-angularfire

Comment: @ninjadev1030 I tried the command that you posted but I got a bunch of npm errors

Comment: @ninjadev1030 I used that link before but it didn't solve my problem because I am already up to date on my firebase download. This issue persists even though I am using the latest version and the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages are pretty clear. You import from wrong paths. Below are some correct examples, look at the import locations.

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

Comment: if you are using IDE with good typescript support like VSCode, you should get visual feedback on the screen during editing time as well.

Comment: I was using Atom, I might switch to VSCode. Thank you for your help.

Comment: And install the TSLint and Angular 6 Snippets extensions

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your import statements. For example, to import the auth and db modules, you should do:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
```

The documentation gives a [full upgrade path](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md#removing-angularfire-for-modularity).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it out.

Comment: So I tried it out but the issue is still the same: src/app/app.module.ts(18,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angularfire2/auth'.

Comment: Hmm, then it sounds like a build system problem. Are you using webpack? If so, can you post your config above? Else if you're using the create-angular-app, can you try deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling?

Comment: @QariZakariahSiyaji it looks like that angular package is pretty flaky. Reading the GitHub issues, it seems you may have better luck deleting your `node_modules`, then install `angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3` (specify that in your package.json). It seems that was a more reliable release. Shocking there are so many bad releases of this popular library...

Comment: @QariZakariahSiyaji you deleted your node modules, installed angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3, and are still getting an error? If so, can you please post the full error and verify the version of angularfire2 you have installed is indeed 5.0.0-rc.3?

Comment: I tried to delete my node_modules file but my computer wouldn't let me. My current versions: "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next",
    "firebase": "^5.4.0",

Comment: @QariZakariahSiyaji when you say current versions, are you reading the versions inside of `node_modules/angularfire2` or from package.json? Your package.json can easily be out of sync with what's actually installed and you're actually requiring. You should always check `node_modules` to determine the version of a troublesome dependency. Also, you should figure out how to delete your `node_modules`. If you're on windows try starting an admin shell. If not you can use sudo if you must, but you really shouldn't have any trouble deleting that folder.

Comment: I managed to remove all of my Firebase code and deleted the node_modules file. I then reinstalled and updated using npm but I am getting even more errors.

Comment: @QariZakariahSiyaji can you update your question to list the errors and your setup? We need all of the gory details to be able to help you...